# Launch 3rd party apps from links (IE: Facebook "App Links")

Tags: ios, ios8, ios8-extension

pretty new to this stuff  - but have a basic question:

I'm looking for a native iOS method that does what Facebook's App Links does.

Put it simply, our news organizations publishes breaking news alerts to Twitter and Facebook with a link to the actual article on our site.  People receive the alert in their news feed on Facebook tap on the link and it goes our mobile web page (because user is on a mobile device).

Now Facebook App Links allows for the link url to open the article in our Mobile App (if the user has our installed or instead our mobile web site).

But iOS 8 includes app Extensions - how can our organization create links to launch our 3rd party apps from Facebook newsfeed or Twitter, etc...?

Is there a native iOS solution to open 3rd party apps? IE: how does google do it on iOS to open Chrome. Is there an iOS 8 App Extension that does this?

Thanks

Comment: You would need a custom URL scheme for this. So that you can open your 3rd party apps using that link. You can take a look at this question, the accepted answer can help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23010915/open-app-from-sms-with-my-url-scheme-as-a-link

Comment: So iOS 8's new App Extensions don't really apply?  All prior versions of iOS could launch 3rd party apps beforehand - using URL schemes?  What added or new features does App Extensions provide in this scenario.  Thank you for expertise!